# Heap is full of PINNED

Tags: haskell, memory-leaks

I have a small program that have reasonable maximum residency but allocates linearly. At first, I thought that should be cons cells or `I#`, but running the program with `-p -hc` shows heap overwhelmed by PINNED. Does anyone understand the reason and/or can suggest an improvement?

The program

```
-- task27.hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.ST
import Control.Exception 
import System.Random
import Data.Functor

import qualified Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U

m = 120

task27 :: [Int] -> (Int, Int)
task27 l = runST $ do 
    r <- V.replicate m 0 :: ST s (U.MVector s Int)

    let go []     = return (1,2)
        go (a:as) = do
          let p = a `mod` m
          cur_lead <- r `V.read` p
          when (a > cur_lead) (V.write r p a)
          go as
    go l

randTest :: 
  Int -> -- Length of random testing sequence
  IO ()
randTest n =
  newStdGen <&>
  randoms <&> 
  take n <&> 
  task27 >>=
  print

main = randTest 1000000
```

My `package.yaml`:

```
name: task27
dependencies:
  - base == 4.*
  - vector
  - random

executables:
  task27:
    main: task27.hs
    ghc-options: -O2
```

My `cabal.project.local`:

```
profiling: True
```

I do `cabal -v0 run task27 -- +RTS -p -hc && hp2ps -e8in -c task27.hp` and get this:

[image: Heap profile]

I tried to add bangs here and there but that did not seem to help.

Comment: This is 35kB, this does not look like "very much". Perhaps you should try to run the program with larger vectors, arrays, and see how the memory profile looks for that.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem residency grows very slowly: e.g. if I change 10^6 for 10^7 in `main`, it changes from 44 Kb to 46 Kb, but I already have to wait non-negligible time (12 secs). I probably should have mentioned another worry of mine: total allocation grows linearly with n :-( But I though this may be connected to the PINNED stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @WillemVanOnsem says, in GHC terms, 35kB resident is miniscule.  Whatever performance issue you have, it's got nothing to do with this tiny bit of pinned memory.  Originally, I said that this was probably the `Vector`s, but that's wrong.  `Data.Text` uses pinned memory, but `Data.Vector` doesn't.  This bit of PINNED memory looks like it's actually from the runtime system itself, so you can ignore it (see below).

In GHC code, "total allocation" is a measure of processing.  A GHC program is an allocation engine.  If it's not allocating, it's probably not doing anything (with rare exceptions).  So, if you expect your algorithm to run in O(n) *time*, then it will also be O(n) in total allocation, usually gigabytes worth.

With respect to the "rare exceptions", a GHC program can run in constant "total allocation" but non-constant time if aggressive optimization allows computations using fully unboxed values.  So, for example:

```
main = print (sum [1..10000000] :: Int)
```

runs in constant total allocation (e.g., 50kB allocated on the heap), because the `Int`s can be unboxed.  For comparison,

```
main = print (sum [1..10000000] :: Integer)
```

runs with O(n) total allocation (e.g., 320MB allocated on the heap).  By the way, try profiling this last program (and bump the count up until it runs long enough to generate a few seconds of profile data).  You'll see that it uses the same amount of PINNED memory as your program, and the amount doesn't really change with the upper limit.  So, this is just runtime system overhead.

Back to your example... If you are concerned about performance, the culprit is probably `System.Random`.  This is an **EXTREMELY** slow random number generator.  If I run your program with `n = 10000000`, it takes 4secs.  If I replace the random number generator with a simple LCG:

```
randoms :: Word32 -> [Word32]
randoms seed = tail $ iterate lcg seed
  where lcg x = (a * x + c)
        a = 1664525
        c = 1013904223
```

it runs in 0.2secs, so 20 times faster.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very helpful. Could you think of a scenario still when one has an O(n) algorithm(along the lines of the example, if possible but not necessarily) with O(1) allocations in Haskell/GHC? That would make your answer even more insightful to me. (I’m going to accept it anyway, I think.)

Comment: Thanks! I hoped for exactly that kind of optimization you showed in my program, actually. I thought that the random numbers should be amenable for unboxing too…